# Which of boost library includes boost spirit?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

Oh well, I can't find this easily. Could you let me know which of boost library includes boost spirit? Is it system or iostream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for 'boost spirit site:boost.org' and you get right to the [Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) page.  Boost is a collection of libraries, this is one such library. You may want to read the introductory documents to learn about download and installation; several Linux distributions would include it premade.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my tremendous ignorance. So according to your answer, when I get boost source code, spirit is not included, right? That's where I am confused.

Comment: It depends what 'boost' is. On my Ubuntu box, spirit is in fact part of the main libboost1.46-dev package, but that reflects also (at least partially) a choice by the Debian maintainer. "It all depends."  What is your platform?

Comment: It's cygwin on windows. I would like to use spirit and am compiling boost. I wonder if I can build one of the components for spirit,

Comment: Spirit may be include, try the cygwin lists. Spirit also is (IIRC) a pure template library. But boost has so many interdependencies. You always end up depending on some other more basic boost libraries.

Comment: I was afraid that. Thanks anyway. HTG to you.